# Как clone() svg элемент?

Tags: jquery, svg

Проблема в том, что нужно клонировать svg элемент и добавить его в другом месте. Использую jquery clone(), но вместо элемента я получаю в html [Object, Object]. Как можно решить эту проблему?

```js
var icons = $("svg").clone();
$(".result").append("<div class='icon-wrapper'><div class='icon-container'>" + icons + "</div></div>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
<svg version="1.1" class="drop-elem__plus" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40px" height="40px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52 52;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M26,0C11.664,0,0,11.663,0,26s11.664,26,26,26s26-11.663,26-26S40.336,0,26,0z M26,50C12.767,50,2,39.233,2,26 S12.767,2,26,2s24,10.767,24,24S39.233,50,26,50z"/>
<path d="M38.5,25H27V14c0-0.553-0.448-1-1-1s-1,0.447-1,1v11H13.5c-0.552,0-1,0.447-1,1s0.448,1,1,1H25v12c0,0.553,0.448,1,1,1 s1-0.447,1-1V27h11.5c0.552,0,1-0.447,1-1S39.052,25,38.5,25z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта часть `+ icons +` преобразует Ваш объект `icons` в строку. И добавляется просто текст в div. Попробуйте так:

```js
let icons = $("svg").clone();
let container = $("<div class='icon-container'/>").append(icons)
let wrapper = $("<div class='icon-wrapper'/>").append(container)
$(".result").append( wrapper )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
<svg version="1.1" class="drop-elem__plus" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40px" height="40px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52 52;" xml:space="preserve">
                                                        <path d="M26,0C11.664,0,0,11.663,0,26s11.664,26,26,26s26-11.663,26-26S40.336,0,26,0z M26,50C12.767,50,2,39.233,2,26
                                                            S12.767,2,26,2s24,10.767,24,24S39.233,50,26,50z"/>
                                                        <path d="M38.5,25H27V14c0-0.553-0.448-1-1-1s-1,0.447-1,1v11H13.5c-0.552,0-1,0.447-1,1s0.448,1,1,1H25v12c0,0.553,0.448,1,1,1
                                                            s1-0.447,1-1V27h11.5c0.552,0,1-0.447,1-1S39.052,25,38.5,25z"/>
                                                    </svg>
```

Это работает, но можно красивее сделать. Но тогда Вам нужно разобраться как пользоваться [шаблонизаторами](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#templates)

Comment: Oleg, можете подсказать как именно добавить если у меня такой вариант $(this).find(".drop-block__list").append("<div class='drop-block__list-item'><div class='drop-block__list-item-icon'>" + icon + "</div><div class='drop-block__list-item-name'>" + name + "</div>" + listItemIcons + "</div>");  icon - Это svg

Comment: @DimaVleskov Обновил ответ. Взял разметку из вопроса. Тут не понятно нифига.